# AngularJS - Change input placeholder dynamically in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<input id="identification" name="identification" type="text" placeholder="{{trackingLoginCtrl.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder}}" ng-model="trackingLoginCtrl.owcsDocument" required="">
<p ng-click="trackingLoginCtrl.clickDotsIcon()">dots</p>
```

And in my controller:

```
clickDotsIcon(){
        let vm = this;

        if(vm.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder === vm.$scope.trackingLoginCtrl.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder){
            vm.$scope.trackingLoginCtrl.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder = vm.owcs.owcsButtonTitle;
        }else{
            vm.$scope.trackingLoginCtrl.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder = vm.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder;
        }       
    }
```

When I click on dots I need to change the placeholder to the new one and if I click on it again to change it back to what it was. I manage to change it to the new one but not back to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your both placeholder values are dynamic and can be changed in runtime, you can handle it in following way.

**HTML**

```
<input id="identification" name="identification" type="text" placeholder="{{trackingLoginCtrl.placeHolderValues[trackingLoginCtrl.currentPlaceholderIndex]}}" ng-model="trackingLoginCtrl.owcsDocument" required="">
<p ng-click="trackingLoginCtrl.clickDotsIcon()">dots</p>
```

**JS**

```
this.currentPlaceholderIndex = 0;
this.placeHolderValues = [this.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder, this.owcs.owcsButtonTitle];
clickDotsIcon(){
    let vm = this;
    vm.currentPlaceholderIndex = Number(!vm.currentPlaceholderIndex);
}
```

Comment: Where does placeholderindex come from?

Comment: To keep track of what value is currently being assigned as placeholder, you will have to introduce a new attribute `currentPlaceholderIndex`.

Comment: I cant declare any variables out of functions (this.currentPlaceholderIndex = 0;) can I put this inside the clickdots?

Comment: Without this, it is not going to be possible. Can you atleast initialize it inside HTML using `ng-init`?  `<input id="identification" name="identification" type="text" placeholder="{{trackingLoginCtrl.owcs.owcsDocumentPlaceHolder}}" ng-model="trackingLoginCtrl.owcsDocument" required=""> <p ng-init="trackingLoginCtrl.currentPlaceholderIndex=0" ng-click="trackingLoginCtrl.clickDotsIcon()">dots</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to change placeholder in dynamically. You can solve your problem following way !

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
   $scope.owcsDocument = '';
   $scope.placeHolderIndex = false;
   
   $scope.clickDotsIcon = function(){
   
   $scope.placeHolderIndex = !$scope.placeHolderIndex;
   }
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="{{placeHolderIndex}}" ng-model="owcsDocument">
    <button type="button" ng-click="clickDotsIcon()">dots</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does placeholderindex come from?

Comment: Also, that changes the placeholder to true or false. I need the placeholder to change from for example, "Hi" to "Bye".

Comment: you may use ternary operator: 


    $scope.placeHolderIndex = 'Hi';

     $scope.clickDotsIcon = function(){
           $scope.placeHolderIndex =$scope.placeHolderIndex == 'Hi'? 'Bye':'Hi';
     }